# The variable in the function is an array but pointers were usen while calling it in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, recurrence, function-declaration

I was looking at my teacher's code and there is something that I could not understand.

This is a recursive function to calculate the sum of the numbers in an array. In the function variables, there is an array but while calling it in the return statements the pointer notations are used. (&A[1] and A+1).

I did not understand that why this code works and why it does not when I change the function variable into `int *A[]`

Here is the code. Thanks a lot.

```
int sum( int A[], int size ){
    if( size == 0 ) return 0;
    print_array( A, size );
    //return A[ size - 1 ] + sum( A, size - 1 );
    //return A[ 0 ] + sum( A + 1, size - 1 );
    return A[ 0 ] + sum( &A[ 1 ], size - 1 );
    
    // n! is n times (n-1)!
    // sum of the elements is first element plus sum of the rest 
}
```

Comment: Arrays *decay* to pointers to their first element. So if you have a proper array (like e.g. `int arr[10];`) then using it as-is will be used as a pointer (e.g. `&arr[0]`).

Comment: The type `int *A[]` is an "array" of pointers to `int` (really a pointer to a pointer to `int`. i.e. `int **`). That's very different from `int A[]` which is an "array" of `int` (really a pointer to a single `int`, i.e. `int *`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. It was really helping.

Comment: And now that you know a little bit more about pointers and how arrays becomes pointers, I recommend you draw your original (*real*) array on a piece of paper. Draw a long rectangle, and divide it into "elements" which you label from `0` to the size of the array (minus one), i.e. the indexes. Now "call" the function, and draw an arrow to element `0`. This is `A[0]` in the initial call. Then you "call" `sum` recursively passing a pointer to the second element (index `1`) so draw an arrow to that element because it's now `A[0]` in the recursive call.

Comment: [Continued] Then you do a second recursive call passing a pointer to `A[1]` which is really the *third* element of the array. So draw an arrow to that, and it now becomes `A[0]` in the new call. And so on...

Comment: I understand the recursion but I had some problem with pointers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A function parameter that has an array type as in this function declaration

```
int sum( int A[], int size );
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the type pointer to the element type. That is these two function declarations

```
int sum( int A[], int size );
int sum( int *A, int size );
```

declare the same one function.

Within the function `sum` the variable `A` is a pointer of the type `int *`.

On the other hand, when you pass an array as an argument expression then it in turn is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

As for this question

> I did not understand that why this code works and why it does not when
> I change the function variable into int *A[]

then this parameter declaration `int * A[]` means an array of unknown size of pointers to `int`. The compiler will adjust this parameter declaration like `int ** A`. But according to the function definition the function expects as an argument an array of integers instead of an array of pointers to integers. Moreover the additive operator `+` is not defined for pointers.

The function provided in your question should be declared and defined the following way

```
long long int sum( const int a[], size_t size )
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : *a + sum( a + 1, n - 1 );
}
```

It seems that your teacher is not a qualified programmer. At least using upper case letters for identifiers of local variables is a bad style of programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now.

Comment: Others may say that an `if` statement is more readable than the ternary operator (`?:`), and less prone to precedence-bugs. Besides, the compiler will probably produce the same output anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Because `&A[1]` refers to an address, while `*A[1]` refers to the value located at address `A[1]`. And `sum()` function needs a pointer to an array and its size.